# Станет ли Хакинтош на Vostro 3550 с i7 на борту  ?

Tags: установка, mac, устройства, ноутбук

В Интернете есть масса мануалов по установки на этот ноут хакинтоша, но с процессором i5. Установится ли он также гладко на этот же ноут, но с более сильным процессором ?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что к программированию вопрос отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант для проверки - попробуйте запустить сие чудо в виртуалбоксе. А так -теоретически встанет. Вопрос - сколько вы готовы претерпеть всяких ухищирений ради запускающейся системы. И сколько ради рабочей.